# Do we need to have configuration files in all mesos masters?

Tags: cluster-computing, mesos, mesosphere, bigdata

I am running a mesos cluster with 3 mesos masters. I have enable authentication and saved a credentials.json file in one of the master. I would like to know if we have to put this file in all 3 mesos masters? Same applies to other files like acls.json and other parameter files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to copy your config files to all masters in the cluster.

Mesos masters do not exchange this configuration information, nor it is persisted across failover. If a currently leading master fails over to another one, you probably want the new leader have the same configuration around authentication and authorization.